# Are hyperref (with dvipsnames) and pdfpages not compatible?

Tags: errors, hyperref, color, packages, pdfpages

I like to have custom-color hyperlinks with

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=NavyBlue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=cyan,
    citecolor=MidnightBlue
}
```

and insert a multi-page pdf document with `\usepackage{pdfpages}`. It works fine (there's no error) when only one of the packages is used.

However, when I included both packages, I got an error that begins with:

```
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 \usepackage
               {hyperref}
The package xcolor has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [dvipsnames]
Adding the global options:
  ,dvipsnames
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
```

I also have multiple other packages, and simply adding `\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{article}` doesn't fix it, but rather causes even more errors.

What causes this? Is there a different package or approach to insert a PDF document that is compatible with `hyperref` with `xcolor=dvipsnames`?

Comment: Pdfpages loads xcolor too. At some time in the future xcolor  will no longer error in such cases but for now use \PassOptionsToPackage.

Comment: Thank you! The order of the packages seems to matter but it worked (`\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{color}` has to come after `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` but before `\usepackage{pdfpages}`).

Answer (score 1):

The error your report is unrelated to hyperref.  Surely you have a situtation like this

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

To fix this do

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

As other packages may load `xcolor` move the `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` earliest possible in preamble.

Answer (score 0):

It works by adding `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}` before `\usepackage{pdfpages}` and after `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` and `\usepackage{hyperref}`; this solution is based on Ulrike Fischer's comment.

Like this:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{...}

\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised that worked.  Usually, `\PassOptionsToPackage` should come before the package is loaded (people will often put it before `\documentclass` just to be sure).  BTW, hyperref should be loaded last, with few exceptions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/107497